# setting variables inside a Laravel foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've just started using the framework. In plain PHP after the opening `foreach` I would then set the variables then close the php tag but then from what I can work out you have to then do the Laravel `@foreach` tags and then open and close `@php`. Is there a way around this as it seems like a lot of extra work and code?

```
        @foreach($steps as $row)
            @php
                $title = $row->title;
                $text = $row->text;
                $i = 1;
            @endphp
            <div class="steps-item grid-wrap">
                <div class="number"
                @if($text || $title)
                    <div class="text-wrap">
                        @if($title)
                            <h2>{{$title}}</h2>
                        @endif
                        {!! $text !!}
                    </div>
                    @php
                        $i++;
                    @endphp
                @endif
            </div>{{--END steps-item--}}
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Couldn't/shouldn't this be done in the controller or model?

Answer (score 2):

Since blade is no PHP, you have to return to PHP with that directive. But you can set/use the variables without doing that in your case:

```
@foreach($steps as $i => $row)
    <div class="steps-item grid-wrap">
        <div class="number"
        @if($text || $title)
            <div class="text-wrap">
                @if($title)
                    <h2>{{ $row->title }}</h2>
                @endif
                {!! $row->text !!}
            </div>
            @php
                $i++;
            @endphp
        @endif
    </div>{{--END steps-item--}}
@endforeach
```

If you still want to set variables, there's a Laravel package called [`alexdover/blade-set`](https://github.com/alexdover/blade-set). But as @brombeer pointed out, in most cases it's highly recommended to set all necessary variables in the controller before passing them to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel provided loop variables:

```
$loop->iteration    The current loop iteration (starts at 1).
```

It will increment in every loop iteration automatically.

```
e.g:
First iteration = $loop->iteration => 1 ;
Second iteration = $loop->iteration => 2 ;
so on until loop ends.
```

Check docs:
[The Loop Variables](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a @for directive with sizeof($steps) like that:

```
@for($i=0; $i<= sizeof($steps)-1; $i++)

@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

@foreach ($steps as $row)

```
<div class="steps-item grid-wrap">
    <div class="number">
        <div class="text-wrap">
            @if ($row->title != '')
                <h2>{{$row->title}}</h2>
               /* if you want to display another title when its blank you can 
                use if-else here otherwise not need to use if conditions for 
                title and text */
            @endif
            @if ($row->text != '')
               {!! $row->text !!}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endforeach

{{--
for an example you have $steps values like

$steps =
Array(
[0] -> 1,
[1] -> 'title',
[2] -> 'text'
);

if you want this array key value pair you have to use @foreach like
@foreach ($steps as $key=>$value)
@endforeach

you can use key value in @foreach loop only
--}}